# Inner Join entre duas tabelas

Tags: mysql, query

[image: img]

tentei assim mas está errado

```
SELECT * FROM produto 
INNER JOIN familiaproduto 
ON familiaproduto.idfamiliaproduto = produto.idNomeProduto 
INNER JOIN qualitygate ON (qualitygate.idQualityGate = produto.idQualityGate1 and qualitygate.idQualityGate = produto.idQualityGate2 and qualitygate.idQualityGate = produto.idQualityGate3)
```

Como faço este `inner join`?
e já agora a estrutura(modelação) destas duas tabelas está correta ou existe outra maneira de fazer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Esse seu `JOIN` vai funcionar somente se o produto tiver o mesmo `idQualityGate` em todas as três colunas que você tem para isso (`idQualityGate`, `idQualityGate2`, `idQualityGate3`).

Parece que você quer um `OR`, que encontrará registros se pelo menos um dos 3 campos existir na tabela `Quality_Gate`:

```
INNER JOIN qualitygate 
ON qualitygate.idQualityGate = produto.idQualityGate1 OR 
   qualitygate.idQualityGate = produto.idQualityGate2 OR 
   qualitygate.idQualityGate = produto.idQualityGate3
```

Isso também pode ser escrito assim:

```
INNER JOIN qualitygate 
ON qualitygate.idQualityGate IN (produto.idQualityGate1, produto.idQualityGate2, produto.idQualityGate3)
```

Se o que você quer é trazer 3 quality gates por produto, você precisa de 3 JOINs:

```
SELECT * FROM produto 
INNER JOIN familiaproduto 
ON familiaproduto.idfamiliaproduto = produto.idNomeProduto
INNER JOIN qualitygate qualitygate1 
ON qualitygate1.idQualityGate = produto.idQualityGate1
INNER JOIN qualitygate qualitygate2
ON qualitygate2.idQualityGate = produto.idQualityGate2
INNER JOIN qualitygate qualitygate3
ON qualitygate3.idQualityGate = produto.idQualityGate3
```

Eu ainda recomendaria selecionar só o necessário de cada tabela, em vez de pegar tudo com o `*`.

Comment: Perfect. No primeiro código só estava a imprimir 1(dos 3) inner join assim funciona perfeito, Obrigado...

Comment: Detalhe: todos os produtos precisam ter os 3 campos preenchidos. Se tiver algum com `NULL`, troque os `INNER JOIN` por `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Ok, acho que vou precisar desse detalhe, muito obrigado...